# Successful Bamboo build transitions JIRA Issues

Tags: jira, bamboo

I'm trying to get Bamboo to update the status of linked issues.

The issues are in a "Build" status, and there's a transition from that, into "Done", that uses the properties taken from docs (Page 62 https://confluence.atlassian.com/alldoc/files/104824976/JIRASTUDIO-June2011_PDF.pdf) + the example Builds workflow.

`build.passed.transition  => true`

The issues are properly appearing in the Bamboo build page.

When the build completes, the Build appear under the "Development" section of the JIRA issue, with a link to it.

But it stays in the "Build" status.

What's the proper way to have Bamboo execute the transition?